# Is there a difference between these two Search Statements Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a situtation in which I need to get the top 15 rows from Table where the `iFlag` column is marked 0.

So i have these two statements:

```
var t = dbContext.UnProcessedLogs.Take(15).Where(up => up.iFlag == 0).ToList();


var unProcessedlogs = dbContext.UnProcessedLogs.Where(up => up.iFlag == 0).Take(15).ToList();
```

What is the difference between the two statements?

Will the first one work if the top 15 rows have `iFlag` marked as 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one will:

1. Take the first 15 rows of `UnProcessedLogs`
2. Then filter those down to those with `iFlag == 0` (which can be less than 15 obviously)

The second one will:

1. Filter all the rows of `UnProcessedLogs` down to those with `iFlag == 0`
2. Take the first 15 of those

If the table have 30 rows, where every other row have `iFlag == 0` and the ones inbetween have `iFlag == 1`, then:

1. The first query will return 7-8 rows (of the first 15 in the table, pick the ones with `iFlag == 0`)
2. The second query will return all 15 with `iFlag == 0`

Answer (score 1):

First version : Take me 15 item, filter on them.

Second version : Take me all item, filter on them, take only 15 of the filtered items.

No, it's not the same.

Yes, they will "work", but won't do the same.

> Will the first one work if the top 15 rows have iFlag marked as 1

this will just return an empty resultset.

This is not an error, it's just probably not what you want !